# Graphql to accept list of user defined objects

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

I have a requirement where i have to accept the list of objects.

The method in mutation class looks like this

```
@GraphQLMutation //1
    public void ack(@GraphQLInputField List<PingEntity> pingEntityList) { //2
        log.info("Handling ack calls.");        
        pingEntityRepository.savePingEntityList(pingEntityList);
    }
```

PingEntity looks like this

```
@Data
//@Document(collection="pingdatastore")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class PingEntity {

    private String id;

    @JsonProperty("action")
    private String action;

    @JsonProperty("message")
    private String message;

    @JsonProperty("timestamp")
    private Long timestamp;

    @JsonProperty("transactionId")
    private String transactionId;

    @JsonProperty("type")
    private Integer type;

    private String imei;

}
```

my query looks like this

```
mutation ack {
  ack(pingEntityList: [{action: "KEEP-ALIVE2", message: "Keep alive message at regular intervals", timestamp: 1462747047}]) {
    id
  }
}
```

I got the Error like this:

```
"data": null,
  "errors": [
    {
      "validationErrorType": "SubSelectionNotAllowed",
      "message": "Validation error of type SubSelectionNotAllowed: Sub selection not allowed on leaf type Boolean",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "errorType": "ValidationError"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried giving different annotations. i am not able to solve this issue.. need help in this issue

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that your `ack` method returns `void` which gets mapped to `boolean`, for the lack of a better option. As `boolean` is a simple scalar, you can not select anything from it, and you're trying to select an `id` in the query.

If you'd change your `ack` method to return the saved `List<PingEntity>`, you'd get the behavior you wanted.

But... more importantly, what library are you using, as the annotations I see (`@GraphQLInputField`) in your code are *not* from graphql-java (as graphql-java itself provides no annotations), nor from any of the libraries I recognize.

It seems to be coming from a really old and never publically released version of graphql-spqr. If this is indeed the case, you absolutely need to update to the latest as the version you seem to be using was alpha quality at best.